# Connecting two CMOS transceivers on different boards

Tags: digital-logic

I have a main board (with DSP controller & CMOS Transciver) and an daughter board (with CMOS Transciver, Ethernet & GPIB controller). these two boards are connected with DIN connector with flexible PCB.

Output pin of the CMOS Tranceiver in main board - has 23.7 Ohm 
Input pin of the CMOS Tranceiver in daughter board - has 22 Ohm

Pls let me know what could be the purpose of these resistances.?

Answer (score 1):

They are series source terminations which are used to match a driver impedance to the transmission line (trace) impedance. A resistor can be placed in series with the transmission line at the driver. Since these are transceivers and bidirectional, they are placed at both ends. Google 'characteristic impedance', 'transmission line' and 'termination schemes'. Basically, you want the driver plus the series termination resistor to equal the impedance of the trace (typically 50ohms). So if the trace is designed to be 50ohms, and the driver impedance is known to be 27 ohms, then a termination resistor of 50ohm - 27ohms = 23ohms is needed.